# Inserting nodes before elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying manipulate a webpage to start adding several elements before a specific element.

To be specific I am trying to insert heading and p tags, before a h3 on a page. My code currently looks like this.

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var elmnt = document.createElement("h3");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("Behind the Scenes of The Lion King at the Lyceum Theatre");
    elmnt.appendChild(textnode);
    var item = document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[3];
    item.before(textnode);
  })();
</script>
```

This is inserting the text ""Behind the Scenes of The Lion King at the Lyceum Theatre" to the page, however it is not in the heading 3 tag. Is there a better method to use to start adding multiple elements before the heading?

Webpage: https://www.thelyceumtheatre.com/tickets

[Screenshot of rendered HTML once adding the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zMPc.png)

Comment: Can you please provide a working example of your code that clearly showcases the problem you have?

Comment: Hi, the attached image shows the issue. I am trying to append the new h3 element, before another one. But, this renders as just #text, rather than within a <h3>

Comment: You want to put a `<h3>` element into another `<h3>` element?

Comment: No, I want to create a new one before the <h3> element. Essentially I want to add formatted text before the <h3> E.G. <h3>Heading</h3><p>This is text</p><p><More text</p> - if this makes sense.

Comment: Confused with what you're trying to do. You append the text to the newly created `h3`, but then instead of inserting the `h3` (elmnt ) you insert the textNode.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `insertBefore()` method. Usage is quite simple:

You need to call it on the **parentNode** of the element you want to prepend the new element. To get it's parent node:

```
var item = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");
item[0].parentNode
```

`insertBefore()` needs two non-optional parameters. The first obviously is the element you want to prepend and the second the target element - thus your `<h3>` element.

Here's an example (just click on 'Run code snippet'):

```js
var elmnt = document.createElement("h3");
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Behind the Scenes of The Lion King at the Lyceum Theatre");
elmnt.appendChild(textnode);
var item = document.getElementsByTagName("h3");

item[0].parentNode.insertBefore(elmnt, item[0]);
```

```html
<h1>H1</h1>
<h2>H2 -1</h2>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<h2>H2 -2</h2>
<h3>H3 -1</h3>
<p>lorem ipsum.</p>
<h3>H3 -2</h3>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<h2>H2 -3</h2>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the parent element of the header, you can use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) to append a node before one of the parent's children.

```js
const insert = (x) =>{
  var elmnt = document.createElement("h3");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("Behind the Scenes of The Lion King at the Lyceum Theatre");
    elmnt.appendChild(textnode);
    var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
    parent.insertBefore(elmnt, parent.children[parent.children.length - 2]);
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <h3>Insert Before Me</h3>
  <button onclick='insert()'>Insert</button>
</div>
```